# How to make portuguese language option in Spring Boot work on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, internationalization

So I created an internationalization system for my Spring Boot project following exactly as in this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization

I've set the main language as Portuguese and created a `messages_en` for English option. I also set the localeResolver to: `localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt", "br"));`

it works fine when I run it locally, but when I deploy to Heroku, I can only see the English version, even though it's not the main language, even when I select the Portuguese option manually, it still shows up in English.

My heroku default region is USA, but I tried it on a server in the Europe region and nothing changes. Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

> **Locales are no longer part of the stack**
>
> Locales are instruction sets used by some programs to perform operations such as number formatting, string collation or date representation according to a language and/or region.
>
> Starting with Heroku-16, locales are no longer part of the stack, and instead installed via a separate buildpack.
>
> If your app requires locales, create a `.locales` file in the root directory of your app’s codebase that lists all the locales you need. For example:
>
> de_DE
> fr_FR
>
> After you have git added the `.locales` file and git committed the change, you may then prepend the heroku-community/locale buildpack to the list of buildpacks used by your app:
>
> `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/locale`
>
> The heroku-community/locale buildpack will then run as the first step of your builds, and install the desired locales for use by subsequent buildpacks and at runtime.

(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-16-stack#locales-are-no-longer-part-of-the-stack,
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale)